# node.js express session access token doesn't persist after changes

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, express-session

I'm quite new to OAuth and not sure what to do with the access token I receive from another party. Right now I'm using express session on https with secure and httpOnly settings. This works fine, until I upload an image on the same API server (which happens after I add a product). Everytime my server detects changes, the token I saved becomes undefined, this means that the user has to go through the whole OAuth process again.

Since I use MYSQL, is it possible to save the token information in the database (expiry, refreshtoken, accesstoken) linked to the user or is there a better way to save this data?

My setup is very basic, I have one API Server and one React app for front-end.
I receive the token information by making an API call with my own API to the other party, the response from this party is what I end up sending as cookies to the React app.

This is the session code I have right now:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    name: "token",
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
```

Comment: Is the express app an API only? And where does the token come from initially?

Comment: @VictorioBerra Hi, the express app is an API only (with images in public, these get added when the user adds a new product). For front-end I use React. I updated my question with some more information.

Comment: Could you react JS app store the token in local storage and then send that with every request to your API? This is how libraries like this work https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki but that might be a little different because that is when you want to use the token to auth to the API, it sounds like this is "machine-to-machine" also known as client credentials where the API needs a token to talk to another API right?

Comment: Is the token is from say Okta, or Auth0, IS4, or Azure B2C, and the whole point is to pass to the API with every request where the token is then validated and used for authorization, you should just keep the token local in local storage and **do not use session in express**. You should also use code as your response_type and use PKCE as that is currently the best practice right now. Find yourself a good OAuth2 react library and let that do the heavy lifting for you. The big ones actually use IdentityModel/oidc-client-js IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into the same problem, by default express session uses MemoryStore. I missed this when I was reading the documentation.

> MemoryStore is purposely not designed for a production environment. It
> will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single
> process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

To fix this, you can use either "cookie-session" or pick one of the stores from the documentation.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores